My Switch statement ends even though it should scan for user input
This is all of the code used for my little test program.
You can run this and it'll present you with two options. either an APY Calculator or a check calculator.
if you run through the APY calc. it will eventually finish its process and return to the original question. However if i run the check calc. it will reach the end of its program and then exit without asking for user input. I have run the program in debug mode and it seems to run through "getUserSelection1" -> "getIntInput" -> "getStringInput" and in here is where the issue seems to begin. if i run any of my code it returns here (line.168 if you put it into any programming application) and asks for user input with the
String line = scanner.nextLine();

but then after running my check calc it just skips over it and doesn't ask for any more input. And since no input is equal to -1 it ends.
package MCS;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mcs {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new mcs().processUserSelections();
    }
    
    private void processUserSelections() {
    boolean done = false;
            
    while (!done) {
        try {
            int selection = getUserSelection1();
            System.out.println(done);
        switch (selection) {
            case -1:
                done = exitMenu1();
                break;
            case 1:
                APYCalc();
                break;
            case 2:
                checkCalc();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\n" + selection + " is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                break;
        }
    }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\nError: " + e + " Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private boolean exitMenu1() {
        System.out.println("Exiting the menu.");
        return true;
    }
    
    private void APYCalc() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
            System.out.println("Enter Your Savings: ");
            double savings = scanner.nextDouble();
    
            System.out.println("Enter Your APY: ");
            double APY = scanner.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.println("Enter how many years you want to iterate: ");
            int iter = scanner.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Enter how much will you put in every year: ");
            double input = scanner.nextDouble();
            
            APY(savings, APY, iter, input);
        }
        
    public static void APY(double savings, double APY, int iter, double input) {
            double increasedSavings = 0, totalEarnedFromBaseValue = 0;
            
            if (APY >= 1.00) {
                APY = APY / 100;
            }
            System.out.println("Starting Value: " + savings);
            for(int i = 1; i <= iter; i++) {
                increasedSavings = savings * APY;
                
                savings += increasedSavings;
                
                totalEarnedFromBaseValue += increasedSavings;
                
                savings += input;
                
                DecimalFormat df_obj = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                
                System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n" 
                        + "This year increase " + df_obj.format(increasedSavings) 
                        + "\nAll years increased added together: " + df_obj.format(totalEarnedFromBaseValue)
                        + "\nAmount put in savings this year: " + input 
                        + "\nTotal for year: " + i  
                        + "\n" + df_obj.format(savings) + "\n");
        }
    }
    
    private void checkCalc() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            double totalHours = addHours();
        
            System.out.println("Enter Your Hourly Pay: ");
            double DPH = scanner.nextDouble();
        
            System.out.println("Enter Your State Tax: ");
            double state = scanner.nextDouble();
        
            System.out.println("Enter Your Federal Tax: ");
            double federal = scanner.nextDouble();
        
    
        System.out.println(taxedIncome(totalHours, DPH, state, federal));

    }

    public static double taxedIncome(double hours, double DPH, double state, double federal) {
        double gross = hours * DPH, sS = .062, medical = .0145, sSTax = 0, medicalTax = 0, taxedIncome = 0, federalTax = 0, stateTax = 0;
        if (state >= 1.00) {
            state = state / 100;
            System.out.println(state);
        }
        if (federal >= 1.00) {
            federal = federal / 100;
            System.out.println(federal);
        }
    
    
        sSTax = gross * sS;
    
        medicalTax = gross * medical;
    
        federalTax = gross * federal;
    
        stateTax = gross * state;
        taxedIncome = gross - medicalTax - federalTax - sSTax - stateTax;
    
    
        return taxedIncome;
    }
    
    private int getUserSelection1() throws Exception {
        printOperations1();
        
        Integer input = getIntInput("Enter a menu selection");
        
        return Objects.isNull(input) ? -1 : input;
    }
    
    private void printOperations1() {
        System.out.println("\nThese are the available selections. Press the Enter key to quit:");
        operations1.forEach(line -> System.out.println("   " + line));
    }
    
    private Integer getIntInput(String prompt) throws Exception {
        String input = getStringInput(prompt);
        
        if (Objects.isNull(input)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new Exception("'" + input + "'" + " is not a valid number.");
        }
    }
    
    private String getStringInput(String prompt) {
        System.out.println(prompt + ": ");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        
        return line.isBlank() ? null : line.trim();
    }

    private double addHours() {
        double inputHour, totalHours = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Type 0 to finish adding hours " + 
                    "\nEnter Hours: ");
            
            inputHour = scanner.nextDouble();
            
            totalHours += inputHour;
            
        } while (inputHour > 0);
        System.out.println("Total hours: " + totalHours);   
        return totalHours;
    }



    // @formatter:off
    private List<String> operations1 = List.of(
                    "1) APY Calculator",
                    "2) Check Calculator"
            );
    
    // @formatter:on
}

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to help me!!! Have a good night.
completely change dhow my code ran. originally picking hack calc would bring you to another menu similar to the first one you see and it asks if you want to input a total number of hours or have the program add it up for you. I was hoping that removing the second switch statement would fix the issue. but it didnt.

This question is answerable in its current state, but there's a lot of code here that's not directly contributing to the problem, which makes it harder to parse. Please [edit] your question to convert the sample to a [mre] - this will help you get answers more quickly as well as increasing its long-term value for other users.
